# I need to find time complexity of the following code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

Here's the code that I want to find time complexity:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   for(int j=i; j<i*i; j++){
      if(j%i==0){
         for(int k=0; k<j; k++){
            printf("*");
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Is it O(n^8) or O(n^6) or O(n^5)?

Comment: Why do you think it is O(n^8)?

Comment: I've found it with actual sequence formulas, it give me O(n^6). But someone finds it O(n^8). But I don't think so, O(n^8) is appropriate.